What is the composition of Zn-Sb azeotrope?
What is the composition of $\ce{Zn-Sb}$ azeotrope? What about boiling temperature?
I found somewhat related data, but not a conclusive answer, by searching the following:

Boiling point of zinc from Wikipedia


1180 K


Boiling point of antimony from Wikipedia


1908 K


Melting points of compounds are lower than melting point of pure
antimony, and there is no two-liquid immiscibility gap. This
indicates the low stability of all compounds on the binary phase
diagram (No information given about boiling temperature.)
Computational methods here fail to reproduce even the compounds'
stoichiometry. However, the


experimental formation energy of $\ce{ZnSb}$ is 0.099 eV/atom.


Are you sure that Zn+Sb form an azeotrope?

Pr even that this is kniwn? Literature diagrams include only solid-liquid equilibria.

@Poutnik Sure enough to ask the experts.

@OscarLanzi What's the point of this site if one could ask the literature directly?

It is very difficult to create a peak on a very steep curve.

@Poutnik Zinc side may be steeper than the region from compounds to antimony. Miscibility does not imply the bonds are all broken.

From this pubs.acs.org article (visible free part) and solid/liquid phase diagram chart, one could imply MeOH and H2O may form an azeotrope, forming MeOH.H2O(s) compound. But they do not. And there is much better slope condition for them to form it.

@Poutnik There are different possibilities: Either the vapor has significantly higher concentration of larger molecules near 50:50 composition than near pure components or the small molecules (atoms in some cases) evaporate one-by-one at every composition. The latter is true for your example, I'm not so sure about $\ce{Zn-Sb}$ , though.
